# User feed page on the Web

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, android-app, stackexchange.com, android-app-feed

I love the feed view in the new Android app. Definitely helping me to discover new content on other sites me than I every have before.

Can we have a feed page on stackexchange.com, giving the same basic functionality as there is in the Android app feed page (auto updated every few minutes)?

Answer (score 5):

This is planned, but not for anytime in the immediate future. We're hoping to use the limited user set on the app(s) to make sure the feed logic scales well, and to also make it smarter using the extra information we get for how people react to it. After this, we can start planning where/how to display it on the main websites.

Comment: Four months passed, any updates? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I wish. Still, not for the immediate future. If we were to add it to the websites right now it'd probably crash our infrastructure for it.

Comment: Any update now...? :)