# Inbox updates outpacing Question/Answer Caching in Android App

Tags: bug, answers, notifications, android-app, caching

I [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217936/51) a few minutes ago (from the Android app, if it matters). An answer was provided, and within seconds of it being answered, the push notification registered on my phone that an answer has been provided.

Clicking on the notification loaded the Answers view for the question. However, no answer showed up. Refreshed - nothing. There was obviously some caching happening that was preventing the answer from being loaded. Interested in seeing how long it would take, I tried to refresh the answers on the phone every 5-10 seconds. In the end, it took the answer around 2.5 minutes to show up on the phone (counting from when the notification came through).

I would expect that when I get a notification of an answer and click through in the Android app, that the answer will be waiting for me when I get there. And if it is not, that manually refreshing will always pull the current data.

Comment: I've noticed this too. It's because all of the read-only calls are coming from a read-only replica database used by the API and it lags behind a bit. I'm aware of the issue but I don't know if we'll be able to fix it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi any way to have a special case for the API to use the live DB (and not replica) in special cases (redirect from push notification, manual answer refresh)?

Comment: Yes, but since the API the app uses will soon be public that would be ripe for abuse.

Comment: There are ways to mitigate the potential abuse. But a different idea : Include the answer or comment data with the push notification about new activity and update from there.

Comment: The push notification has a hardset about of bytes it can be since it relies on piggy-backing off Google's internal calls (use for keep-alive on Google Talk). I think adding it to the API and protecting it from abuse is the best way, but that would have to wait until after the current version of the API becomes public imo.